# "An error has occured in the claims providers configured from this site collection" My Sites Set-up error

Tags: claims, mysites, my

I'm trying to set-up My Sites. I have the web application created, the top level site collection configured, permission policies set. I go into my user profile service to finish the set-up, but when I go to set the read permission level I get "An error has occurred in the claims providers configured from this Site Collection." [image]

This didn't happen on my development site. I have my Alternate Access Mappings set-up, and the site can be pinged, etc.
Any advice? Google is telling me people only experience the problem with AAM not being configured properly, but mine is.

This may be related, but I also can't change the search center settings. The "Search scope for finding people," and, "Search scope for finding documents," only have the value "Select a search scope." My development site also doesn't do this. My development and live site are nearly identical mirrors of each other, so I have 0 idea of what the problem could be.

MySites host is an independent site collection, using HSNC.

Comment: Do you got any resolution for this? I am having the same issue.